# How to supress stdout and stderr message when using pkill

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to kill some process in `ubuntu 18.04` for which I am using `pkill` command. But I am to able to suppress `Killed` message for some reason. 
Here is process which are running.

```
# ps -a
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
   2346 pts/0    00:00:00 gunicorn
   2353 pts/0    00:00:00 sh
   2360 pts/0    00:00:00 gunicorn
   2363 pts/0    00:00:00 gunicorn
   2366 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

My attempts to kill the process and supressing logs

```
# 1st attempt
# pkill -9 gunicorn 2>&1 /dev/null
pkill: only one pattern can be provided
Try `pkill --help' for more information.

#2nd attempt (This killed process but got output `Killed` and have to press `enter` to get into command line)
# pkill -9 gunicorn > /dev/null
root@my-ubuntu:/# Killed

#3rd attempt(behavior similar to previous attempt)
# pkill -9 gunicorn 2> /dev/null
root@my-ubuntu:/# Killed

root@my-ubuntu:/#
```

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: `pkill -9 gunicorm > /dev/null 2>&1` ?

Comment: @Archemar Behavior is same with above command as well

Answer (score 0):

Ah - I suspect it is output from the thing BEING killed, not from the kill operation.
So you might have success in dumping stderr from that process - or you might need to grep out the KILLED lines from its stdout.
It's not very pretty is it!